# How to set ajax scripts in web application source code?

Tags: c#, jquery

I am trying to hide and show text boxes using jquery. But when I select the ajax library from c# solution explorer script folder, I am not getting expected output but when I use the CDN library it works. How to set this library to get expected output?

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="~/Default.aspx.cs"     
Inherits="WebApplication1._Default" %>                     
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<%--<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"> 
          </script>--%>//it works fine
<script src="Scripts/jquery-1.4.1-vsdoc.js"></script>//not works
<script src="Scripts/jquery-1.4.1.js"></script>//not works
<script src="Scripts/jquery-1.4.1.min.js"></script>//not works
<script>
$(function () {
    $('input[name="type"]').on('click', function () {
        var name, comp;
        if ($(this).val() == 'Experienced') {
            $('#txtname').show();
            $('#txtcomp').show();
            $('#Label1').show();
            $('#Label2').show();
        }
        else {
            $('#txtname').hide();
            $('#txtcomp').hide();
            $('#Label1').hide();
            $('#Label2').hide();
        }
    });
});
</script>
<style type="text/css">
    .style1
    {
        width: 100%;
    }
    .style2
    {
        width: 132px;
    }
</style>
</head>
```

Comment: Try adding `~/` in front of the path e.g. `<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.4.1-vsdoc.js"></script>` this will make the path relative.

Comment: @sa_ddam213, Not working

Comment: add just slash `/` like `<script src="/Scripts/jquery-1.4.1-vsdoc.js"></script>` in this case url is relative app folder

Comment: @sa_ddam213, Sorry not working.Is it necessary add these three libraries???

Comment: what you mean _not working_? any error in console? also you add reference twice to one lib: `<script src="Scripts/jquery-1.4.1.js"></script>//not works`
`<script src="Scripts/jquery-1.4.1.min.js"></script>//not works`

Comment: Grundy,No error but wen I click on radio buton text boxes are not hiding.

Comment: i'm not sure, but `on` in jQuery from 1.7, [jQuery.on](http://api.jquery.com/on/) - _version added: 1.7._, are you sure that no error in console?

Comment: try update nuget version jQuery in your project, and retry again

Comment: @Grundy,Sorry I dont know how to update nuget version in my project.If you don't mind please explain to me.

Comment: about working with nuget see [docs](http://docs.nuget.org/docs/start-here/managing-nuget-packages-using-the-dialog)

Answer (score 0):

Myself found answer for my question.If in future anybody face this type of error they can use this method.what I do to solve this issue I downloaded Microsoft jquery libraries. Here are the links

```
 http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.7.js    
 http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.7.min.js    
 http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.7-vsdoc.js
```

now add 3 new jquery items into your solution explore and named as jquery-1.7.js,jquery-1.7.min.js and jquery-1.7-vsdoc.js.Now Open above links in a new tab and copy whole content and save according to the jquery folder name.after that add this libraries into your project

```
<head>

          <script src="jquery-1.7-vsdoc.js"></script>
          <script src="jquery-1.7.js"</script>
          <script src="jquery-1.7.min.js"></script>
</head>
```

Thank you. All the best :)

Comment: You are right. This is the jquery version problem. I have deleted my answer. Since your javascript code is using on() function, and this function is only available after jquery version 1.7. 
http://api.jquery.com/on/